# How to test the web on ipad or other android‘s telephones?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I want to test my web on ipad or others.But i don't know how to do. I want to see display in different screen.And I want to test the function on different platform. Can you tell me any tools or any website ?

Comment: What do you mean by "testing your web"? Maybe it's just me but this question (in current form) doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to test your app on an iPad ? If that's what you mean then you need a developer account (developer.apple.com), then register the device. There are guides in the Dev Library for that :)

Comment: This should really be a comment since it is not an answer.

Comment: Needed 50 reputation so couldn't. And it is an answer, I told the OP what to do didn't I ? And where is your answer ? :p

Comment: Aha, my bad. Sorry. :) As for my answer: i don't have it since i'm not really sure what the OP is actually asking for :)

Comment: Lol same for me :p just guessed

Comment: NO,I only want test my web.

Comment: I want to know if CSS OR JS is useful on IPAD

Comment: Wait so you have a website that uses CSS and JS that you want to test on the iPad ? or is it an app ? Sorry, your question is still a bit unclear :)

Comment: Because in different browser，I don’t know my website will show what???